# Upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, upgrade, content-porter-2013

We are planning to upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1. As part of that, we are planning to move our Databases from Oracle to SQL Server.  We are planing to maintain parallel environments as we dont want to disturb the existing environments where development is going on.

What is the best way for migrating the content. I am thinking about using content porter. But can we use content porter for porting content between different CM versions such as 2011 SP1 to 2013 SP1?

Answer (score 5):

**You can Content Port from earlier versions of Tridion in to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1** - I did this recently, between Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 and Tridion 2013 SP1.

One thing to note is that you will need the **Content Porter 2013 SP1 Client** to be able to import in to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. Although SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 now comes with the Import/Export Webservice as part of the Core Content Manager (CM) installer, you will still need to get the Content Porter 2013 SP1 installer to make the Content Porter client available within the `Tools` menu.

[image]

You will need to consider that there is a small list of [Known issues](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-FF9E5ED8-1B59-4027-BEA8-E13D75636375) (login required) with Content Porter 2013 SP1.

However, **the biggest thing to note** with this approach of using Content Porter, is that **there are a number of items that are not exported when using Content Porter**.

The full list can be found on [the Non-exportable items page](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8) of the SDL Content Porter 2013 SP1 online documentation (login required). However, the main 'non-exportable items' to note in your situation are probably:

- Publication Targets and Target Types in publishing
- Page and Component publishing status
- Users
- Security settings for Users and Groups
- Permissions for Publications, Folders, and Structure Groups

You will need to ensure that there is a content freeze in place during the migration period.

It may be worth doing a few 'dry runs' on the migration, and saving the Content Porter configuration each time (and possibly scripting the migration), so that you can reduce the chance of forgetting something.

You may want to discuss your situation with Tridion Support or Professional Services, as they may have encountered this situation before.

Comment: Also worth noting, content porting the entire Tridion BluePrint might have some pain points and will definitely take a bit of time. You will need to increase timeout and package size settings to allow this size of import/export.

Comment: A very good point, Chris. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Jonathan & Chris, What about Content Data Store. Need to republish all sites once content is successfully moved?

Comment: @user1453602 Yes, you will need to re-populate the Broker database with a re-publish. This is the most reliable way of keeping your Content Manager and Broker databases consistent (with what has been published to where). Also, when you Content Port, your IDs will be different, so the old (Oracle) Broker database information won't relate to your new (SQL Server) content.

Comment: @Jonathan, Our new environment will be on cloud.  We will be exporting content from current PROD (Tridion 2011 SP1)which is hosted in house. Do we need content porter client 2013 sp1 in our current PROD to be able to export content? Or export taken using current content port can be imported using Content porter 2013 SP1on cloud environment. ?

Comment: @user1453602 When you do an export using Content Porter 2013 SP1 Client, it asks you whether your 'destination' CMS is Tridion 2013 or earlier.  Therefore, I assume that the export packages are different for each. However, I exported from Tridion 2011 using the old Content Porter 2011 Client and then imported in to Tridion 2013 SP1 with the new CP Client, so it must be backwards compatible with the old (2011 format) of package.  Please post your findings back here.

Comment: Sure, Jonathan, Project is yet to be started.  I will surely put my findings here and queries as well ;)

Comment: @Jonathan, We have around 70 publications, 300+ users, 200+ user groups. We will be exporting content using Content porter 2009 SP2, and will import same package using Content Port 2013.  We will have to create all users, user groups manually ?  is there any OOTB feature available which can be used to do this? We are thinking of creating users, user groups through core service.  When we will start with project we may face more issues should I create new question?

Comment: There is no 'out of the box' tool to do this. You should check out Dominic's blog post for hints on doing this with the Core Service: http://www.indivirtual.nl/blog/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/

Comment: @Jonathan, We started with content port, initially we faced timeout issues we increased timeout settings. It is working fine. But yesterday we started getting below error.                                                      "The transaction associated with current connection has been completed but has not disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statement."

Comment: @user1453602 Not one I've seen before I'm afraid. I think you should raise that as a separate question, or with Tridion Support. You're more likely to get a faster answer that way.

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard of a switch between oracle and sql server before.

I doubt it's possible to content port from 2011 SP1 over to 2013 SP1, but certainly worth a trail run, it it works great.

If it doesn't work, then you're best best is to upgrade your existing CM and CM DB up to 2013 SP1 and then from there you can use Content Porter to move the publications and content from your old CMS (using oracle) over to your new CMS based on SQL server.

Comment: It really depends on the version of Content Porter, but ports across Tridion versions is generally possible with two catches. 1. It's typically allowed for the latest major or service pack versions so sometimes an upgrade is needed. 2. All the functionality in later versions can't be kept for an older version. For example Bundles can't be ported into a Tridion version before 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally I thought you've only been able to content port to/from the same version.

According to the [2013SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6DE876E8-7B31-4B5D-8410-B2B4F4414242) doc you can `Content Porter supports transfer between different versions of Content Manager`

**Edit**

[Content Porter 2013 SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-BF8E808B-89B8-443E-A26A-FDBF2FCAF7C8&addHistory=true&query=content%2520porter&scope=&tid=8fc511eb-50d4-4080-943f-57b96718542b&filename=GUID-BF8E808B-89B8-443E-A26A-FDBF2FCAF7C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-BF8E808B-89B8-443E-A26A-FDBF2FCAF7C8&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dcontent%2520porter&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1404317948799&currentQuery=content%2520porter&currentScope=) can connect to any Tridion server version as of 2011 SP1 HR1 (so, 2011 SP1 HR1, HR2 and 2013 GA and SP1).

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. I updated the first link to the specific SDL Live Content topic that describes transfers between Tridion versions. I kept your original overview link but moved it to the edited section.

Comment: Thanks Alvin - a few interesting 'reminder' points throughout this thread overall!

Comment: Hello, I have tried to export content from Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 using Content Porter 2013 SP1. Then, I have tried to import that file in a Tridion 2013 SP1 using Content Porter 2013 SP1. I have got an error message: Version of the package c:\..... is not supported. ¿Do I have to do the export using other version of Content Porter?