# Content Porter: Export from Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 to Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: content-porter, content-porter-2013-sp1

My final goal is migrating some content from a Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 to a Tridion 2013 SP1.
According to the SDL documentation, Content Porter can do that: http://tinyurl.com/pfnovv9

I also reviewed this question:
[Upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/upgrade-to-tridion-2013-sp1)
And it suggest that what I am trying can be done.

I am using Content Porter 2013 SP1 to perform both the export and the import. The export goes well but when I try to import the package, I get this error:

> Version of the package c:..... is not supported

What am I missing?

I noticed that when doing an export from a Tridion 2011 environment, even using Content Porter 2013, I get the typical options of old Content Porter (I mean, I am not asked if destination environment is 2013SP1 or 2013 or lower for example).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried exporting using content porter for 2011 sp1 and import using 2013 sp1?

Comment: Yes, with same results: the package I got exporting from 2011 SP1 is not valid for Content Porter 2013 SP1.

Comment: Which version of Content Porter (server) do you have installed on your 2011 SP1 server?   CP 2013 SP1 is only a client and is compatible with CP 3.3 server IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Review the following link where Brandon added some extra comments that might be usefull for you

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7B19341C-7E20-48BA-BAB0-46E3D3D84469

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, using content porter 2013 for export, import should work.

There is one alternate approach that you can use:

> 1. Take backup of 2011 CM database, restore it as some other database.
> 2. Upgrade restored CM database to 2013 sp1 (by using tridion upgrade documentation)
> 3. Point any 2013 sp1 CM to the upgraded CM database temporarily to generate export package.
> 4. Use this exported package to import in the destination.

The above solution should work without any issue.